# When I run an HTML file in live server, it is always being shown in a new window

Tags: visual-studio-code, live-preview

When I run an HTML file in live server in Visual Studio Code, it is always being shown in new a window, so I have to flip to the next window to see the result. The live server is not showing the output just beside the HTML page. How can I see the output just beside the HTML page in VS Code?

Comment: That's what it's supposed to do, it doesn't embed a browser view into the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From [Visual Studio docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html)

> #### Does VS Code have HTML preview?
>
> No, VS Code doesn't have built-in support for HTML preview but there are extensions available in the VS Code [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode). Open the Extensions view (`Ctrl+Shift+X`) and search on **'live preview'** or **'html preview'** to see a list of available HTML preview extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plugin you can use to get your output shown inside the IDE.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=auchenberg.vscode-browser-preview

[image]

In the original functionality and feature set, VS code doesn't have built-in support for what you are looking for. IT just launches the browser and shows the output for your source file.